# How do I raise my cities' strength?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I have problems regarding my colony's strength points. Whenever I look at rivals' cities, they have strength points in the hundreds.

How do I raise my cities' strength points ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase city strength by building defensive buildings,activating a specific National Security Project ,by growing the city and by building it on specific terrain.

To break it a bit down:

- a city built on a hill has a stronger base strength than a city built on plain land
- garrisoned units on the city tile will add city strength(I'm not 100% sure about that,but it was the case in civ5)
- when a city grows,it's Hitpoints and Combat Strength increase
- Having the [Homeland Security Project](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Covert_Operations_(CivBE)#National_Security_Project) enabled will increase City Hitpoints and Strength by +1% per Agent at HQ
- the following Buildings will increase Combat Strength of your City*: Command Center(+20/+20),Defense Perimeter(+10/+40),Node Bank(+24/+10),Rocket Battery(+18/+15)
- some [quests](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Quests_(CivBE)) will give you the opportunity to increase Combat Strength of your cities**: Spymaster and Commander(Command Center/+15), The Observable Universe(Observatory/+2), Too much gun(Rocket Battery/+5), The ghost in the machine(Node Bank/+10%)

*scheme is Name(+City Strength/+City Hitpoints)

**scheme is Questname(Trigger/+City Strength)